# Color of the button "Kolonie" typography stays the same even after changing it many times

Tags: css, button, menu, dropdown

So i tried changing it from #E3CC82 to #1F1F1F but it just wont let me. Tried many things, as well as putting it into chatgpt. Nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .navbar .menu-items ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 20px;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .navbar .menu-items ul a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #E3CC82;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 0.7rem;
    }

    .navbar .menu-items ul a:hover {
      font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .kolonie-btn {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #E3CC82;
      padding: 8px 37px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: #1f1f1f;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
    }

    .kolonie-btn:hover {
      background-color: white;
      transform: scale(0.95);
      color: #1f1f1f;
    }

    .nav-container {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      height: 60px;
    }

    .nav-container .checkbox {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      height: 32px;
      width: 32px;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 5;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-container .hamburger-lines {
      display: block;
      height: 26px;
      width: 32px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 2;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav-container .hamburger-lines .line {
      display: block;
      height: 4px;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #E3CC82;
    }

    .nav-container .hamburger-lines .line1 {
      transform-origin: 100% 0%;
      transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-container .hamburger-lines .line2 {
      transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav-container .hamburger-lines .line3 {
      transform-origin: 100% 100%;
      transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar .menu-items {
      padding-top: 120px;
      background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.9);
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(150%);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-right: -40px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
      text-align: center;
      overflow-y: hidden;
}
.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .menu-items {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #E3CC82;
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #E3CC82;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container nav-container">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="menu-toggle" />
        <div class="hamburger-lines">
          <span class="line line1"></span>
          <span class="line line2"></span>
          <span class="line line3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Aktualności</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projekty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wsparcie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a class="kolonie-btn" href="#">Kolonie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script>
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
    menuToggle.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        document.body.style.height = '100vh';
      } else {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
        document.body.style.height = 'auto';
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help

I tried changing the color of the parent, but that just changes colors of everything. I tried changing the colors in the code that doesnt work as well

Comment: You can change it from class to id.  ((#) id has higher precedence than (.) class).

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.kolonie-btn {
        color: #1f1f1f !important;
    }
```

Comment: Wow why are the answers always so easy

Comment: It's normally not really recommended to use important unless totally essential. Try to get greater specificity without using it if possible (because important overrides anything that may come after as well as before in the cascade).

Comment: @ChristianKozyge <3

Comment: @AHaworth yeah. 1) Inline style: Inline style has highest priority among all.
2) Id Selector: It has second highest priority.
3) Classes, pseudo-classes and attributes     christian, You should learn these too.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the rule is overwritten by **.navbar .menu-items ul a {}**.

You need to be more specific when targeting the button. Just use the same descendant combinator:

```
.navbar .menu-items ul .kolonie-btn {
     /* style the element */
}
.navbar .menu-items ul .kolonie-btn:hover {
     /* style the element */
}
```

You can also do this by using the !important flag, but I personally would recommend avoiding the use of !important as much as you can.